# How to exclude root tag -element from jaxb wrapper?

Tags: xml, spring, jaxb

There is app on spring+jaxb+jpa

So, I have rest - controllers and jaxv Elements:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
@Getter
public class UserWrapper {
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Users")
    @XmlElement(name = "User")
    private List<User> Users;

    @XmlElement(name="UserError")
    private UserError error;
}


@Getter
@Setter
@XmlRootElement(name="User")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User{
  @XmlElement
  private String name;
  @XmlElement
  private String surname;
}
```

There are User entity and Wrapper for contain List of Users.

Response from my controller is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <Users>
        <User>
            <Name>AAA</Name>
            <Surname>AAA</Surname>
        </User>
        <User>
            <Name>BBB</Name>
            <Surname>BBB</Surname>
        </User>
    </Users>
</root>
```

How to make response without  tag ?

Rest controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody UsersWrapper findByParams(
            @RequestParam(value = "id") String id) throws Exception {
        RiskMetricError error = null;
        List<User> users = userService.find(id);

        return (new UsersWrapper(users, error));
    }
```

P.S.
I need to  make response xml like this:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
        <Users>
            <User>
                <Name>AAA</Name>
                <Surname>AAA</Surname>
            </User>
            <User>
                <Name>BBB</Name>
                <Surname>BBB</Surname>
            </User>
        </Users>
```

Comment: may you clarify what you mean by "How to make response without tag ?"; how should the response be?

Comment: @AngeloImmediata updated.

Comment: @AngeloImmediata yes, but there is error message :org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.Collections$SingletonList

Comment: So, on stackoverflow I accept advise - use wrapper.

Comment: I was wrong so i deleted my comment... I'll think on your issue and I'll let you know... sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparing the two xmls (actual vs desired) you do not want to have the users content within the `<root>`. You can do this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Users")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Users {

    @XmlElement(name = "User")
    private List<User> users;
}
```

Then User will be:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class User {

    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    private String name;
    @XmlElement(name = "Surname")
    private String surname;
}
```

A small spring boot application to try it out:

```
@RestController
public class UsersEndpoint {

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public Users getUsers() {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
        users.add(new User("name1", "surname1"));
        users.add(new User("name2", "surname2"));

        return new Users(users);
    }
}
```

Will return this:

```
<Users>
    <User>
        <Name>name1</Name>
        <Surname>surname1</Surname>
    </User>
    <User>
        <Name>name2</Name>
        <Surname>surname2</Surname>
    </User>
</Users>
```

Update to reply to comment (elaborate on the answer):

Your POJOs and your xml structure should match. The annotations help "smooth" differences. You had `<root></root>` because your root class UserWrapper  had this annotation: `@XmlRootElement(name = "root")`. If in the name you had "blah" the external tags (`<root></root>`) would be `<blah></blah>`. Additionally above your list of users you had this annotation: `@XmlElementWrapper(name = "Users")`. This created an extra wrapper element outside your list elements with the provided name.

So what I did is properly name the root element and remove the extra wrapper element creation.

Comment: @VladislavOsipenkov I will update the answer with an explanation